# How to check Toolbar title in android instrumental test?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I found great instrumental test tutorial on YT [Advanced Android Espresso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlHJFZvZyxw#t=7m40s). I took code from there with small adjustment to my needs.

```
import static android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withChild;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withParent;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.allOf;

...

@Test
public void checkToolbarTitle() {
    String toolbarTitile = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getString(R.string.my_bus_stops);
    onView(allOf(isAssignableFrom(TextView.class), withParent(isAssignableFrom(Toolbar.class)))).check(matches(withText(toolbarTitile)));
}
```

Unfortunatelly it does not work for me. Test failed with:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.TextView and has parent matching: is assignable from class: class android.widget.Toolbar)
```

What is wrong with it? How can I test it in other way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The method is fine. As Chiu-Ki Chan wrote in her [tutorial](http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/05/espresso-match-toolbar-title.html) you can "pinpoint that one particular view". 
**BUT you have to make sure you imported proper Toolbar:**

```
import  android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

instead of:

```
import android.widget.Toolbar;
```

Answer (score 33):

This works for me:

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(TextView.class), withParent(withId(R.id.toolbar))))
    .check(matches(withText("toolbarTitile")));
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It was the import as Grzegorz Bielanski posted.  instanceOf could not be resolved for me.

Comment: Just wondering why are you down-voting?! It works for most of the cases (see amount of votes) and the fact that it doesn't work for you doesn't make this answer incorrect.

Comment: How do I know it works for "most of the cases". My experience is that what works on Android changes from version to version, and a relevant answer today is not sure to be relevant tomorrow.

Comment: @gr envoy How do you know that your experience and point are valuable for this answer? Just don't downvote if it doesn't work for you, leave a comment. You should appreciate people effort first.

Comment: @denys I up voted this answer. This case worked for me. And I came across this answer when I was having a similar problem. And the fact that this answer still works more than a year on. Casts doubt on GR Envoy assumption that it could break tomorrow.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an alternative (and more idiomatic approach):

```
onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).check(matches(hasDescendant(withText(toolbarTitle))))
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using an ActionBar, not a Toolbar, use this:

```
onView(allOf(instanceOf(TextView.class), 
     withParent(withResourceName("action_bar"))))
        .check(matches(withText("My ActionBar title")));
```

---

<sup>Note: To quickly add the imports for these methods, put the blinking cursor on the unresolved method, then do Android Studio ➔ <kbd>Help</kbd> ➔ <kbd>Find Action</kbd> ➔ search for `"show context action"` or `"show intention action"` ➔ click on the result option ➔ A popup window will appear ➔ click on `"Import static method ..."`. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to "Show Context Actions". [More info here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/intention-actions.html). Another way is to enable `"Add unambiguous imports on the fly"` in the Settings.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember if I wrote this myself, or if I found it somewhere, but this is how I check toolbar titles:

```
public static Matcher<View> withToolbarTitle(CharSequence title) {
    return withToolbarTitle(is(title));
}

public static Matcher<View> withToolbarTitle(final Matcher<CharSequence> textMatcher) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, Toolbar>(Toolbar.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(Toolbar toolbar) {
            return textMatcher.matches(toolbar.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with toolbar title: ");
            textMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }
    };
}
```

This works with all cases. Example assertion: `onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).check(matches(withToolbarTitle("title")));`